# Convering a list into an array of dtype = int64

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list

```
y_test  = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

type(y_test)
Out[597]: list
```

I would like to convert this into an array of dtype `int64`.

```
y_test
Out[598]: array([1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 0, 1], dtype=int64)

type(y_test)
Out[599]: numpy.ndarray

y_test.shape
Out[600]: (25000,)
```

Kindly note the shape of the result. 
Is this something achievable?

Comment: `np.array(y_test, dtype=np.int64)`?

Comment: @ayhan - This has worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ayhan if you can publish your answer, i will accept it. In case if you are nt seeing this, I will publish on your behalf and accept. Thanks so much again

Comment: Just a minor question: How can a length-20 list be interpreted as shape `(25000,)` array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function [`np.array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) can take any sequence and convert it to a numpy array. For your case, this would be

```
np.array(y_test)
Out: array([0, 0, 0, ..., 1, 1, 1])
```

You can also specify the dtype argument if you wish:

```
np.array(y_test, dtype=np.int64)
Out: array([0, 0, 0, ..., 1, 1, 1])
```

Comment: Specifying the `dtype=np.int64` is especially important on windows where the default integer type is `np.int32`. :)